# How do I get all products that are displayed on a page?

Tags: catalog, products, product-collection, catalogsearch, magento2.4.3

I am trying to get all the products which are displayed on the current page. The information is used for tracking cookies on the page.ready call.

It was possible to get the product from the product page using the Registry class, on the cart and checkout pages I can use the Cart class. How can I get the currently **displayed** products on the catalog page?

Both classes are deprecated as I am on magento 2.4.3 .

Comment: are you talking about Category Page Collection, right?

Comment: Hey @DhirenVasoya, yes the category page. Similar to this thread, but I don't know how it can be done in magento 2. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141645/get-product-ids-of-current-category-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to the `$collection` you can use a jQuery to parse all ids:

```
var productIds = [];
jQuery('.product-items').find('[id*=product-item-info_]')
    .each(function (i, e) {
        productIds[i] = parseInt(e.id.replace('product-item-info_', ''))
    });

console.log(productIds);
```

Result:

[image: Result in console on category view page]

But better way is to take all ids right from the product collection:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var productIds = '<?= $_productCollection->getAllIds();?>'
</script>
```

Magento does not use any ui-components in the standard product listing block, so they cannot be detected using the registry.

#### Update

You can add own block to the layout:

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="category.product.list.additional">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\CategoryAdditional" name="additional_products_info_js" template="Vendor_Module::products_additional_info.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Block code:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/CategoryAdditional.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class CategoryAdditional extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getCollection() {
        return $this->getLayout()->getBlock('category.products.list')->getLoadedProductCollection();
    }
}
```

Template where you can use the product collection to fill your javascript object (you can get a sku, name and other information right from the collection):

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/products_additional_info.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var \Vendor\Module\Block\CategoryAdditional $block */
?>
<h3><?= __('Product ids');?></h3>
<?php
$productIds = $block->getCollection()->getAllIds();
echo implode(',', $productIds);
// Add relevant script here, it's just a sample code which will render all the ids
?>
```

Results (tested with standard layered navigation):

11 products:

[image: Products 1]

With filter (1 product):

[image: Products 2]

Comment: Hey Siarhey, I think I have access to the ProductCollection in my Block. But I want only the products that are visible to the user on one page. The collection gives me all Products in the shop, no matter on which page I am. 
Is there some way to filter it to the current page?

Comment: Using the jQuery approach, I have a phtml file, which provides my javascript File with information like so:
´
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Vendor_Module/js/myJavascriptFile": {
                "currentProducts": "<?= json_encode(array_values((array)$currentProducts), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) ?>"
            }
`

As I need the name and the sku in my javascript File, how can I proceed after providing the Id's to my javascript file?

Comment: Or can I load the Id's with jQuery and then get the name and sku in the same phtml file in the '<script type="text/javascript">' part with inline php??

Comment: @Max I've updated the answer: added example with layout and new block.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the category page, then you can get collection by :

```
<?php $_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection(); ?>
```

Where `$block` is object of `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`

Comment: Thanks Dhiren. I created a ListProduct object in my Block. The Block itself is of the Type: Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
My findings were, that it did not matter on which page I was. 
The collection from getLoadedProductCollection() gave back all Products in the Shop, even though on the single Product site (catalog_product_view), there is only one product.

Is it, because my Block is of the wrong Type?

Comment: Yes the block must be on this type, then you will get proper output.